# Using ucfirst() function in php 5.3 returning a parse error

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, ucfirst

I'm trying to add a ucfirst() function in my codeigniter controller so I'll get back a string with a first upper case letter. For some reason I keep getting a parse error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ... on line 7 (the line where my ucfirst is).

Trying to change ucfirst() to ucfirst(strtolower($database)) or to ucwords($database) returning the same result.

My code is:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Somecontroller extends CI_Controller {
    private $database = "some_database";
    private $model = ucfirst($this->database)."_model";
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

> declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You should initialise `$model` property in class constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
   // I guess you'll need to call parent constructor as well
   parent::__construct();
   $this->model = ucfirst($this->database) . '_model';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $this->database and assign in your constructor

Something like:

```
function __construct()
{
   $this->model = ucfirst($this->database) . "whatEver";
}
```

Comment: You're right! I fixed my mistake but I'm still getting that parse error...

Comment: See my change...use the constructor...

Comment: Moved it to my constractor but still getting a parase error:      Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE

Comment: @Lior declare your variable before the constructor with `private $model;`, and use it directly in the constructor with `$this->model`, you don't redeclare it as `private` there

Comment: Marko, thanks!!! I declare the variables at the top and used them in my constructor and... it works! Thanks!